# I have an error when updating my single-spa to React 18

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, upgrade, react-18

I'm working on a single-spa React version 5.9.4, which currently it is configured with react 17. But when I try to update to React 18, it doesn't recognize the createRoot method from DOMClient, which is set up like this:

[react-mf-hello-world.tsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGkDC.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOMClient from 'react-dom/client';
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react';

import Root from './root.component';

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOMClient,
  rootComponent: Root,
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  errorBoundary(err, info, props) {
    // Customize the root error boundary for your microfrontend here.
    return null;
  },
});
export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles;
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emddy.png)

*Even though I have configured React 18, it's using the render method, so it behaves like React 17.

#### ** Uncaught TypeError: application '@react-mf/hello-world' died in status SKIP_BECAUSE_BROKEN: m.createRoot is not a function**

versions dependencies of my proyect:

- react 18.2.0
- react-dom 18.2.0
- single-spa 5.9.4
- single-spa-react 5.0.0
- webpack 5.75.0

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it! The problem was that I needed to update the cdn react version of the root project of my single spa.

Comment: Please mention more details like which version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it without changing the react version anywhere.

The `single-spa-react` supports and can accept [all these object properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr40K.png).

We can see that `renderType` can have [these possible values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrZox.png).
We have to select `createRoot`.

So overall your `index.js` code can look like

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import singleSpaReact from "single-spa-react";

const RenderApp = (props) => {
  console.log({ props });
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
};
const appLifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  renderType: "createRoot",  // Pass this prop in order to correctly identify createRoot
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: RenderApp,
  errorBoundary: () => {
    return null;
  },
});

// const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
// root.render(<RenderApp />);

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = appLifecycles;
```

Hope that helps.